# dataframe with two conditions on two different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a dataframe based on two conditions on two different columns. In the example below,  I want to filter the dataframe `df` to contain rows such that it contains `uid`s with value counts for the `val` column greater than 4 is more than 2.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4],'iid':[11,12,13,12,13,13,14,14,11,12], 'val':[3,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,3,4]})`

For this dataframe, my output should be

```
 df
   uid  iid  val
0    1   11    3
1    1   12    4
2    1   13    5
5    3   13    4
6    3   14    5
7    4   14    4
8    4   11    3
9    4   12    4
```

Here, I filtered out the `uid` 2 becuase number of rows with `uid == 2` and `val >= 4` is less than 2. I want to keep only `uid` rows for which number of `val` with values greater than 4 is greater than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `groupby.transform` with `sum` once check where val is greater or equal `ge` than 4. and check that the result is `ge` to use it as a boolean filter on df.

```
print (df[df['val'].ge(4).groupby(df['uid']).transform(sum).ge(2)])
   uid  iid  val
0    1   11    3
1    1   12    4
2    1   13    5
5    3   13    4
6    3   14    5
7    4   14    4
8    4   11    3
9    4   12    4
```

EDIT: another way to avoid `groupby.transform` is to `loc` the rows where val is `ge` than 4 and the column uid, use `value_counts` on it and get True where `ge` 2. then `map` back to the uid column to create the boolean filter on df. same result and potentially faster.

```
df[df['uid'].map(df.loc[df['val'].ge(4), 'uid'].value_counts().ge(2))]
```